# char* and char[] not getting same output

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, system-calls

I have taken the function argument as char*, in my case I get XOR equal to 210. On the other side, In the other VS I took the first argument not char* but simply char[] and the XOR is 114, which is correct.

what's wrong? why can't I get the same thing here?

thanks for your replies.

UPDATE: You are right. sprintf() works fine. The problem is the rest of the code.

```
bool BuildAnglePacket(char* WR_PacketAZAngle, float AZAngle)
{

    WR_PacketAZAngle[0] = 0x04;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[1] = 0x30;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[2] = 0x31;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[3] = 0x02;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[4] = 0x79;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[5] = 0x4E;
    WR_PacketAZAngle[6] = 0x48;

    int  XOR;
    char HAnlge[9];
    int iAzimuthAngle;

//    AZAngle = 22;

    if (AZAngle >= -22.5 &&  AZAngle <= 22.5)
    {
        iAzimuthAngle = AZAngle*10;

        if( AZAngle < 0)
        {
            iAzimuthAngle= abs(iAzimuthAngle);
            iAzimuthAngle=((~iAzimuthAngle)&0xFFFF) + 1 ;
        }

        iAzimuthAngle = 65536 + iAzimuthAngle;

        sprintf(HAnlge,"%08X", iAzimuthAngle);

        WR_PacketAZAngle[7]  = HAnlge[0];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[8]  = HAnlge[1];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[9]  = HAnlge[2];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[10] = HAnlge[3];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[11] = HAnlge[4];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[12] = HAnlge[5];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[13] = HAnlge[6];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[14] = HAnlge[7];
        WR_PacketAZAngle[15] = 0x03;

        for(int i=4;i<16;i++)
            XOR ^= WR_PacketAZAngle[i];

        WR_PacketAZAngle[16] = XOR;
        WR_PacketAZAngle[17] ='\x0';
    }

    return true;
}
```

Solved: Yes, I forgot to initialize XOR.

Comment: Since you are adding 65536 (0x10000) to your small number, how could the third hex digit be anything other than 1? Linux's `sprintf` output appears correct (except that you don't show the exact value of `iAzimuthAngle`).

Comment: How are you calling sprintf with a single character instead of char* without getting a compilation error? Also, hex 96 is 150, not 15.

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable, example that doesn't behave how you expect, along with your expectation?

Comment: @riv I suspect it's a mistake introduced by copying - the actual code likely invokes `sprintf_s` correctly.

Comment: How does that compile? `HAngle` is a single character, not a pointer or array. Any why do you expect 65536+15 to be 0x96 not 0x1000f?

Comment: Regarding the update: you don't initialise `XOR`, so its value is indeteminate. Change the declaration to `int XOR = 0;`.

Comment: You did not initialize the `XOR` variable.

Comment: Could it be that in your VS version you had the angle to which you add `0x10000` and then `sprintf_s()` out declared as `short int`,  will say as 16bit integer?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not with `sprintf_s` or `sprintf`. Value 65536 + 150 => 65686 => 0x10096.

This is the correct result as printed by your code, anything else would be a bug. BTW, I think you meant 150, not 15, as 0x96 => 150.

can it be that iAngle in your Windows version is unsigned short, so it wraps around and you actually get 150 instead of 65536+150? This would explain output of '00000096' but it means that it is a bug in the original calculation code, not with printing itself.

BTW, I assume that real code doesn't have `char HAngle;` but something like `char HAngle[..];` otherwise anything can happen in case that compiler for some reason falls asleep and doesn't produce an error.

EDIT:
The updated code shows that `XOR` is not initialized and it can contain anything before it is used in calculation, so you can get any result. You have to set it to 0 first. On Windows side it probably worked if you were testing the debug version which sets integral variables to 0 or by pure chance.

Comment: yes I allocated char packet[18]; before calling the function above.

Comment: ok - then check the type of `iAngle` in windows code. What compiler are you using?

Comment: iAngle is integer. the compiler is visual c

Comment: windows xp, VS 2010. VS program communicates well with digital Board. So, its output 114 is correct. The problem comes from my implementation of the function in Linux which gives output 210.

Answer (score 2):

```
int iAngle = 15; // for example
char HAngle;

iAngle = 65536 + iAngle;
```

So `iAngle` == `65536 + 15` == `65551` which in hex is `0x0001000F`. If you printed that to a string, shouldn't you get the following?

```
[0]    48 '0'
[1]    48 '0'
[2]    48 '0'
[3]    49 '1'
[4]    48 '0'
[5]    48 '0'
[6]    48 '0'
[7]    70 'F'
[8]    0 '\0'
```

Surely index `3` must always be a hex `1` in this case?

It looks like the windows function is doing something strange...

Also `HAngle` should be an array if you're going to print to it, otherwise you're way overflowing the storage allocated to it. You seem to be able to treat it as a pointer when you call `sprintf` so I'm assuming you mean `char *HAngle` and have allocated memory for the buffer before you print to it?

**EDIT:** From your updated code it looks like `XOR` is not initialised? If it isn't then it could start with any random value (compiler doesn't have to set it to zero I'm afraid:) ). This could account for the different results. On both sides it could have an arbitrary initial value and just so happens on one side to have a zero initial value...

Comment: yes I allocated char packet[18]; before calling the function above.

Comment: Ok. XOR is not initialised - this could be the issue

Answer (score 2):

The original question doesn't make much sense: the code won't compile unless you change `HAngle` to an array (or pointer to an array); hex 96 is decimal 150, not 15; and you get the extra `1` because you're adding 65536 (hex 10000) to the value.

In the updated question, you get an indeterminate value for `XOR` (and technically undefined behaviour) since you never initialise it. You want:

```
int XOR = 0;
        ^^^
```